# I'm refactoring nested models to use scope::syntax, how do I update my belongs_to relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I'm going from this:

```
def Book
 has_many :book_chapters

def BookChapter
 has_many :book_pages
 belongs_to :book

def BookPage
 belongs_to :book_chapters
```

and converting it to this:

```
def Book
 has_many ?

def Book::Chapter
 has_many ? 
 belongs_to :book

def Book::Page
 belongs_to ?
```

also, the old way, I could do `<Book Object>.book_chapters` how would I do something similar with the new format?

using rails 2.3.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly tell it what classname to use, so that you can have the association named however you would like.

So:

```
class Book
 has_many :book_chapters, :class_name => "Book::Chapter"
end

class Book::Chapter
 has_many :book_pages, :class_name => "Book::Page"
 belongs_to :book
end

class Book::Page
 belongs_to :book_chapters, :class_name => "Book::Chapter"
end
```